# How to check if an object exists or filename matches in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

example contrived for this question. I want to iterate over objects in a s3 bucket and see if i can find a file/object that matches a particular name. currently i'm iteration over the files ( see sample below) . is there a better way to do this or faster way to find files in aws s3?

```
import boto3
s3_R = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_b = s3_R.Bucket("MyBucket")
files_list = []
for file in files_list:
   if(file.key == "myfile.txt")
       print(file.key)
```

Comment: If you know the filename, why don't you just get it directly? Why would you need to iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the *exact* key

```
response = client.head_object(
    Bucket='examplebucket',
    Key='HappyFace.jpg',
)
```

If no such object matches the key, `S3.Client.exceptions.NoSuchKey` will be thrown. The object data is not transfered to your local, if that's your concern